# Rambam or the Rambam?

Tags: names, speech-talking

It has become regular that when referring to Rambam (and many Rishonim like Rosh, Tosfos etc) people say THE Rambam instead of omitting the seemingly redundant THE.

Is there are a reason for this? Why is it different when people speak of Rashi where the introductory THE isn't said?

Comment: Why is "the" redundant?

Comment: Or, the Chazon Ish.